# Interview question closed as "not a real question"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The question [**123456789 = 100**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521606/123456789-100) has been closed as "not a real question".

From [What is a “closed” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583):

> **not a real question**
>
> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous and vague, and cannot be answered in its current form.

But

- It is very easy to understand what is being asked
- The question is not ambiguous, nor vague
- And it **can** be answered

So

Is there another definition for "not a real question" I am not aware of?

Comment: I would improve your title and question. That's probably why it was closed.

Comment: @BrAvada It's not "my" question

Comment: I would also tag it as Code Golf

Comment: btw. I'm quite sure I've seen very similar question on SO or Programmers before, so very possibly it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Wether: Sorry, thought it was. I edited it to improve it and added the tag code-golf

Comment: @vartec Probably. But it is a real question. I think I answered a similar question before too, but can't find it now.

Comment: If I got *that* as an interview question, I'd thank them for their time and exit stage left.

Comment: @Anthony The interviewer is a person, and probably does not represent fully the company views. Also, your comment is too localized ... only valid for regions of the world where there is not a severe employment problem :)

Comment: I think the original close reason was fine. The bigger problem here is that there seems to be no way to close nonsense like this as NARQ when asked during an actual interview. The SO team should look into implementing that.

Answer (score 5):

I agree that it's **not** "Not a Real Question," but it should have been asked on [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) instead, since it doesn't fall in the category (from the FAQ) "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."  It probably got closed as NaRQ because there is no migration path to PP&CG.

Comment: @Bill It was posted in the "interview" category, and the comments seem to confirm that such questions are a commonplace in India

Comment: @Wether: I'm often asked what my greatest strengths and weaknesses are in interviews.  That doesn't make it a good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Bill I am not making a defense for the question. I just think it is a real one (although but probably not good)

Comment: @Bill: How is the question not practical, answerable, and based on a problem the asker might face?

Comment: @BrAvada: Of the three, it's only answerable.  How is it at all practical or based on a problem that someone might face (outside of an interview or a puzzle contest)?

Comment: @Bill: It is in India.

Comment: I migrated it.  Definitely [codegolf]

Comment: @BrAvada: That's going to take a lot more explanation.

Comment: @Bill: Apparently in India it is used on a lot of interview questions.

Comment: @Won't: I was leaning that way, but wanted to see if anyone could find a duplicate.  I know I've seen that question somewhere before but I can't find it either.

Comment: @BrAvada: Being used in interviews doesn't make it practical.  It's a moot point now anyway, since it's off to its new home.

Comment: @Bill: There are plenty of questions which do not get closed or migrated simply because they are interview questions.

Comment: @BrAvada, point us to some of them. If they need to be closed, we'll help.

Comment: @BrAvada: I noticed that.  That's not a reason to keep off-topic questions around though.  If it's a programming question that just happens to be asked a lot in interviews, we can let it stay on SO.  Otherwise, we can see if it would be on topic on Programmers or Code Golf, or another site in the SE network.  If it doesn't fit anywhere (see my first comment for an example) then we need to close it.

Comment: @Bill: Fair enough...

Comment: @Won't The OP does not need a golfed version. What is the point in transforming it in a code-golf challenge?

Comment: @Wether: Go check the faq for [codegolf.se].  Its not exactly what you think.

Comment: @Won't I thought you tagged it as [code-golf] ... shortest code wins ..

Comment: @Wether: no, I migrated to [codegolf.se].

Comment: @Won't So the [code-golf] tag may be the default tag there, as it is tagged that way. That means "shortest code wins". I'm going to retag as [challenge] or something like that. Tnx

Comment: @Wether: Aaah, sorry, didn't understand what you were saying.  Definitely retag.  I didn't touch that.

Comment: Bill, @Won't: As written the question simple doesn't form an acceptable question for CodeGolf.SE. Now that not a huge deal: it has all the makings of a good [code-golf] after a pretty heavy editing job. But the user won't get answers that *explain* how to approach the problem accept from [code-golf], and it is not well suited to a more general [code-challenge] because of the lack of a good metric for evaluating the winningness of answers.

Comment: @dmckee: Thanks for the feedback.  I see I need to spend a little time on PP&CG to get a better feel for the rules there.  One more site to add to my list.  :)

Comment: @dmckee: Its obviously not a code-golf, but I thought it would have been a good one for a challenge.  Is there a good description somewhere (more than in your avg [faq]) about judging the winningness of a challenge answer?  I'd think it would be simple--it meets requirements, is maintainable (not short enough to be obscure but not long either), and shows some elegance in design....